# Botão voltar em Xamarin Cross Plataform

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

Como fazer uma função pra quando clicar em "Voltar" no `Android` em `Xamarin`, o app volte para a tela anterior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falando sobre [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) por "Cross Platform Xamarin", você deve usar o [`OnBackButtonPressed`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/). Mas lembrando como diz na documentação:

> O evento é gerado quando o botão de hardware 'voltar' é pressionado.
>   Este evento não é gerado no iOS.

Basta substituir esse evento em sua NavigationPage e você está pronto para ir:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{    
    // A mágica acontece aqui
    return true;
}
```

Comment: eu tenho uma View principal que ao clicar num botão vai pra view que estou mexendo, ai no caso eu preciso que quando eu clicar no voltar, volte pra view anterior a minha, entendeu ? Só que desta forma não está voltando para ela. Ele fecha o app

Answer (score 1):

Em qualquer Page, você pode sobrescrever este método

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Comment: ainda não está voltando, é que tipo, eu tenho uma View principal que ao Clicar num botão vai pra view que estou mexendo, ai no caso eu preciso que quando eu clicar no voltar, volte pra view anterior a minha

Comment: Me mostra o evento do teu botão. Se você estiver usando PushAsync pra nova Page, ele vai voltar automaticamente quando clicar no BackButton, nem precisa especificar um evento pra isso.

Comment: Ah, não to usando PushAsync não. Vou fazer o teste.

Comment: Você ta fazendo como? Setando a MainPage?

Comment: Faz assim, seta a MainPage como uma NavigationPage(SuaPrimeiraPage). Daí no teu click do botão você coloca Navigation.PushAsync (SuaSegundaPage)

Comment: Isso @Marlon Ribeiro

Comment: funcionou!! Era isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: Legal! Dá uma olhada nesse post aqui que você vai entender como funciona a navegação no Xamarin Forms.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/